# Как прочитать nullable значение из таблицы с помощью reader.GetInt32?

Tags: c#

Числовой столбец в БД может содержать NULL, как правильно его прочитать?

```
try
{
    OracleCommand Orasql1 = new OracleCommand("select * from TMC.AMBRY", CPIcon);
    CPIcon.Open();
    var si = CPIcon.GetSessionInfo();
    si.Territory = "AMERICA";
    si.Language = "AMERICAN";
    CPIcon.SetSessionInfo(si);
    OracleDataReader reader = Orasql1.ExecuteReader();
    int iid = reader.GetOrdinal("ID");
    int iusrid = reader.GetOrdinal("USRID");
    int iroomid = reader.GetOrdinal("ROOMID");
    int iambry = reader.GetOrdinal("AMBRY");

    if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("ID")))

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        AmbryClass ambryClass = new AmbryClass(
        reader.GetInt32(iid),
        reader.GetString(iambry),
        reader.GetInt32(iusrid),
        reader.GetInt32(iroomid));

        model.Ambry.Add(ambryClass);                    
    }               

}
```

Comment: А зачем читать null в БД? Вы проверяете на null идентификатор таблицы. У вас при пустом идентификаторе в таблице может содержаться информация? Если да, то советую перестроить таблицу, чем потом мучатся с кодом в надежде перехватить все ошибки.

Comment: Странный код. Зачем использовать "GetOrdinal"? Вы не знаете структуры таблицы в БД?

Comment: @Tivyram, кроме идентификатора других числовых полей быть не может? Или они все обязаны быть notnullable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSDN рекомендует перед каждым вызовом `GetInt32` (или аналогичного метода) явно проверять запись на значение Null  с помощью вызова `IsDBNull`

См. параграф "Комментарии": https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.getint32(v=vs.110).aspx

Я же вам рекомендую освоить какой-нибудь маппер, например, всеми любимую библиотеку [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/).

Вы просто определяете в своем классе Nullable-поля, а остальную работу поручаете библиотеке:

```
class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
}
```

Код чтения:

```
using (var connection = new OracleConnection("Connection String"))
{
    var users = connection.Query<User>("select * from users");
}
```

"За кулисами" метод расширения `Query<T>` откроет соединение (ели оно не открыто), создаст команду, выполнит ее, прочитает из ридера все столбцы и если в нашем классе есть поля/свойства с такими названиями, то присвоит им значения с учетом их типа (при необходимости будет выполнено конвертирование, например, в БД у вас строковое значение, а мы можем его смаппить на свойство `int`) и с проверкой на null

Comment: Огромная благодарность. Помогли

Comment: Рад, если это так! Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Int - это тип данных структуры. Хранится в стеке и не может иметь значение NULL. Но в базе данных есть колонка типа int и может иметь null. Как же ее получить?
Необходимо использовать Nullable тип.
Позволяет любой структуре хранить значения null. Их часто используют для работы с БД. [Nullable - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx)
Сокращенный вариант:

```
int? iid = reader.GetInt32(iid);
```

Comment: Nullable - хорошо, только `GetInt32` возвращает не Nullable-значение