# Чтение ячеек из SQL базы

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Прошу помощи в организации чтения адресов из базы данных (SQL).
Есть таблица, в которую занесены IP адреса, каким-то образом необходимо организовать чтение этих адресов в переменные, обработку и запись некоторой информации в соседние ячейки.
На данный момент придумал костыльный способ при помощи цикла и идентификаторов int.
Вот так:

```
// СЧИТЫВАЕМ КОЛ-ВО СТРОК В БАЗЕ

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("server = ****; database = Monitoring; Trusted_Connection = True"); // устанавливаем соединение с БД
connection.Open();                                                                           // открываем соединение с БД
string CountQuerry = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Main";                                            // строка с текстом запроса
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(CountQuerry, connection);                                // объект для выполнения SQL-запроса
String CountString = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();                                     // выполняем запрос и получаем ответ
int CountCell = int.Parse(CountString);                                                      // переделываем строковую переменную в числовую
connection.Close();                                                                          // закрываем соединение с БД


//   ОТКРЫВАЕМ ЦИКЛ ПРОВЕРКИ ВСЕХ СТРОК БАЗЫ


int idbd = 0;
while (idbd < CountCell)
{
    idbd++;

    //    ЧИТАЕМ АДРЕС УСТРОЙСТВА ИЗ БД

    connection.Open();                                                                  // устанавливаем соединение с бд
    string sql = "SELECT Name FROM Main WHERE id = '" + idbd + "'";                     // запрос записываем в переменную
    SqlCommand readdb = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);                                // объект для выполнения sql-запроса
    string adress = readdb.ExecuteScalar().ToString();                                  // выполняем запрос и получаем ответ
    connection.Close();
```

Само собой, если последовательность ID будет нарушена такой метод не будет пригоден..
Есть ли более культурные методы?
Просьба за исходник шапками не закидывать, только начинаю

Comment: Используйте `ExecuteReader()`, а не `ExecuteScalar()` — он не для этого предназначен.

Comment: Посмотрите еще этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/791869/218063

Comment: а не проще получить одним запросом всю таблицу в список (например List<T>), а уже потом обработать список. Получать значения перебирая ID - совсем не правильно.

Comment: А можно чуть подробнее? К сожалению не нашел решений, где одним запросом можно заполнить лист из столбца(

Comment: @Семён. Посмотрите примеры с Linq to SQL.  Например https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/4.1.php . С помощью этой библиотеки вы можете выдернуть всю таблицу в List<>  и уже дальше делать с данными всё что угодно. Придется вспомогательный класс сделать,  но по ссылке достаточно подробно написано